# IBM Watson Speech to Text Only Returning First Word With Java SDK

Tags: java, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I'm using the IBM Watson speech to text Java SDK, and when I upload the .wav file the response JSON only contains the first transcribed word. When I upload the same file to the web demo, I get the full response.

Very simple implementation with the SDK:

```
SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");

File audio = new File("src/test/resources/sample1.wav");

SpeechResults transcript = service.recognize(audio, HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV);
System.out.println(transcript);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `recognize()` signature you are using will return after the first pause. To see all of the results do this:

```
RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions();
options = options.continuous(true)
          .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV)
          .interimResults(false)
          .inactivityTimeout(10)
          .maxAlternatives(1)
          .wordConfidence(false)
          .timestamps(true)
          .model("en-US_BroadbandModel");
SpeechResults transcript = service.recognize(audio, options);
```

This works for me using the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Nice, didn't see that documented anywhere.

Comment: This wasn't explained in the answer, but setting the `continuous` option to `true` is the key to retrieving all of the results, not only the results after the first pause.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying quite the same thing, using the same parameters described by Chris K. (except for "interim results = true")

```
    FileInputStream audio = new FileInputStream("/home/leoks/BM/ws/mp32wav/out.wav");

    RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions();
    options = options.continuous(true)
              .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV)
              .interimResults(true)
              .inactivityTimeout(10)
              .maxAlternatives(1)
              .wordConfidence(false)
              .timestamps(true)
              .model("en-US_BroadbandModel");

    api.stt.recognizeUsingWebSockets(audio, options, new BaseRecognizeDelegate() {
      @Override
      public void onMessage(SpeechResults speechResults) {
        System.out.println(speechResults);
        try{
            if (speechResults != null && speechResults.isFinal()){
              lock.countDown();
            }
        }catch(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){
        }
      }
    });

    lock.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

However, it still throws an exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.websocket.WebSocketSpeechToTextClient$WebSocketListener.onTextMessage(WebSocketSpeechToTextClient.java:66)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnTextMessage(ListenerManager.java:352)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnTextMessage(ReadingThread.java:233)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnTextMessage(ReadingThread.java:211)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleTextFrame(ReadingThread.java:910)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:693)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:102)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.run(ReadingThread.java:61)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.websocket.WebSocketSpeechToTextClient$WebSocketListener.onTextMessage(WebSocketSpeechToTextClient.java:66)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnTextMessage(ListenerManager.java:352)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnTextMessage(ReadingThread.java:233)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnTextMessage(ReadingThread.java:211)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleTextFrame(ReadingThread.java:910)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:693)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:102)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.run(ReadingThread.java:61)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.websocket.WebSocketSpeechToTextClient$WebSocketListener.onTextMessage(WebSocketSpeechToTextClient.java:66)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnTextMessage(ListenerManager.java:352)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnTextMessage(ReadingThread.java:233)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnTextMessage(ReadingThread.java:211)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleTextFrame(ReadingThread.java:910)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:693)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:102)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.run(ReadingThread.java:61)
```

which seems to be related to this issue

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/issues/205

that is set to be reached in milestone 2.9.0 (current is 2.8.0)

Comment: It works for me with interim results true. You shouldn't do `lock.countDown()` on `speechResults.isFinal()` though - there are multiple messages that are final (this occurs every time there is a pause in the speech).